Query on UUID _id
I am unable to query on binary UUID?
db={
  "models": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$binary": {
          "base64": "ksIhKC1GSleQMLeuREhjsg==",
          "subType": "04"
        }
      },
      "modelID": {
        "$binary": {
          "base64": "Am6CZhDWSRGouvb6394Nig==",
          "subType": "04"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

When I specify $binary it does not work
db.models.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: {
        $eq: $binary(
          "92c22128-2d46-4a57-9030-b7ae444863b2"
        )
      },
      isDeleted: false
    }
  }])

https://mongoplayground.net/p/tr6EHENSGuG

Like my previous answer to your another question, you probably need to use $function to parse the _id field and query on the parse result like this

This question is similar to: MongoDB lookup join between string and UUID. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It is not supposed to work. $binary is part of Extended JSON notation used to represent data in a human-friendly format.
You cannot use it as an input, the same way as you cannot use $oid, or $date - this is how a mongodb client shows specific data types to you.
The only scalars you can use in a query crafted manually are strings and numbers, and you need to use functions to convert them to actual data type. In your case it would be $toUUID (added in v8.0). Being an expression, the converter cannot be used with "find/$match" syntax directly, and should be applied via $expr query:
db.models.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          "$_id",
          {
            "$toUUID": "92c22128-2d46-4a57-9030-b7ae444863b2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

